# Is cold/heat exposure on topic

Tags: discussion, off-topic

Cold showers can increase metabolism and saunas can have a blood doping effect. Are questions along these lines on topic?

Comment: As Greg says, they *can* be on topic, if they are addressed in the context of using them to improve your fitness/fitness program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the questions are about these sort of tactical uses of saunas/showers (or ice baths, whatever) then I don't see why not. Obviously there is a line here.

Answer (score -2):

Surely questions about hot and cold treatment of the body constitute medical advice?

Comment: No like, cold showers speed recovery, saunas have a blood doping effect, etc

Comment: So...medical advice.

Comment: ... no. Unless you're counting anything related to the body as "medical advice". In general, we've used "medical advice" to avoid giving advice on injuries that are more appropriate to a doctor.

Comment: ...so medical advice then?  Got it.